# get Xpath data comes from External JS

Tags: xpath, extjs

It is simple example HTML for demonstration my issue

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
    <label>This value comes from internal</label>
    <div>
      <div name='internal'>$11.11</div>
    </div>
  <div>
    <label>This value comes from external</label>
    <div>
      <input type ='text' name='internal' readonly='true'>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

//Display in Web Browser

This value comes from internal
11.11

This value comes from external
55.55

I want to get $55.55, but I searched "//*[text()='$55.55']" with inspector but I could not find any $55.55
and I figured out this $55.55 value comes from external JS and changed DOM and display.
This value displayed on browser but I could not get Xpath of input value
How can I get Xpath get this value "$55.55"

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, I dont know if I correctly understand your question, but if your goal is to get the input's value you can do something easy as, without the need of XPath:

```
var myInputValue = document.querySelector('input[name=internal]').value;
console.log(myInputValue);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will test with my test framework... I hope my test framework works with JS.